# ldap server unreachable cause plone/zope server down

Tags: ldap, zope, plone-4.x

I have a plone installation (4.2.5) with **plone.app.ldap** add-on. There is a site with plone-ldap enabled and our ldap server was changed to another domain/IP. So on, zope server downs on plone-ldap retrieving ldap information. Nothing more works even root ZMI.

Any request to server doesn't load anything few seconds after plone restart. Therefore I can't reconfigure our new ldap server neither by our site or ZMI interface.

In such case, How can I proceed to reconfigure the new ldap server on plone-ldap component? Is there some script application similar to ZMI to do this? Is it a known bug?

Some logs:

1) Zeoserver.log

```
2016-06-06T15:52:04 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 40051): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 40051)>
2016-06-06T15:52:04 (127.0.0.1:40049) received handshake 'Z3101'
2016-06-06T15:52:04 (unconnected) disconnected
2016-06-06T15:52:04 (unconnected) disconnected
2016-06-06T15:52:08 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 40052): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 40052)>
2016-06-06T15:52:08 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 40053): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 40053)>
2016-06-06T15:52:08 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 40054): **<ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 40054)>
2016-06-06T15:52:08 (127.0.0.1:40052) received handshake 'Z3101'
2016-06-06T15:52:08 (unconnected) disconnected
2016-06-06T15:52:08 (unconnected) disconnected**
```

2) client1/event.log

```
2016-06-06T15:53:12 ERROR event.LDAPDelegate {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.26-py2.7.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/LDAPDelegate.py", line 366, in search
    connection = self.connect(bind_dn=bind_dn, bind_pwd=bind_pwd)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.LDAPUserFolder-2.26-py2.7.egg/Products/LDAPUserFolder/LDAPDelegate.py", line 265, in connect
    raise e
**SERVER_DOWN: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}**
```

Comment: Had you tried to access the ZMI Zope root with the "admin" user with basic authentication?

Comment: Yes, it works, but drops the server down on accessing the site object. I've found [bug 1218938](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ldapuserfolder/+bug/1218938)  but it doesn't show a fine solution to me.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "drops the server down" ?

Comment: On admin ZMI root view when I click on plone site object (with the ldap add-on I want to reconfigure), the zope server just doesn't work anymore and outputs these logs above. Any request to other site or plone ZMI (even admin) works at all.

Comment: Any browser request to these urls remains on loading status and doesn't produce any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backup first**

*Disclaimer* - I never seen before an LDAP configuration that freeze also the root-level admin ZMI access to the Plone site.

What I can quickly suggest you is to delete the ldap plugin from the site's acl_users and starts from scratch.

As ZMI is not usable you must use the console access.
For doing this run a zope instance as follow:

```
$ bin/instance debug
```

(where "instance" is one of your instances)

The you can delete the ldap plugin:

```
del app.Plone.acl_users['ldap-plugin-id']
```

Where `Plone` is the is of your site and `ldap-plugin-id` the is of the LDAP plugin.
If you don't remember it, look for it in this set:

```
app.Plone.acl_users.objectValues()
```

Finally you must persist your changes:

```
import transaction;transaction.commit()
```

...then exit using `CTRL+D`

Now you must be able to access ZMI and you must create and reconfigure a new plugin.

**Please note**: when configuring an LDAP or AD plugin always set a "Connection timout" and an "Operation timeout". This is probably why your access attempt totally freeze the instance.

Comment: Does it need run buildout (without ldap plugin) and/or inst. restart after these commands?

Comment: No you don't: LDAP configuration is something that live inside the ZODB storage

Comment: Solved @keul. Plugin deleted and sites/zmi accessible again. Just one correction on command `$ bin/instance debug` above. Have you seen the [launchpad bug 1218938](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ldapuserfolder/+bug/1218938) related above? It's possible the cause of this problem.

Comment: It's temptating to upvote this, just so keul passes 4k rep, but of course I would never do that ;) Upvoted for one more very well done explanation.